I am trying to create a VBA to custom sort data
The sort is based on a specific column, across a workbook of 31 sheets. I only want to run the VBA on the sheet that I am working on at the time.  Each sheet is protected and must remain so.
I tried to record a VBA, but it would mean a different CTL+letter command for each sheet.
I actually need to do two types of custom sort, one before the other. That is why I only want to run the sort on the sheet that I am on.
I just need the sorts to be ascending numbers for one and standard, medium and high for the other.  The Macro that was recorded is as follows, but only on one sheet.
Sub OccSort()
'    
' OccSort Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+o
'
    Sheets("VBA test").Select
   ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Range("A2:F502").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("VBA test").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("VBA test").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "A2:A502"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("VBA test", "VBA Test2").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:F502")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("G2").Select
    Sheets("VBA test").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowSorting:=True
End Sub


Please clarify your question.  Worksheets("VBA test", "VBA Test2") is not valid and it seems like you only want to work on the ActiveSheet.  Do you want us to write the second sort for you?  Or do you need the range to be sorted to be dynamic?

@TinMan Don't confuse OP with words range and dynamic. :-)

It seems you want to have possibility to perform the complex sorting procedure by a click. Is it true? Should be this procedure same for all sheets or vary? Is data structure same in all worksheets?

@rotabor to be fair the OP confused me first! FYI Katrina,  our comments are all in good fun.  I've got +20 years of writing buggy code under my belt!

Hi! Not at all surprised by the confusion!! Sorry, no years of Coding experience under any garments at all here!!!

So, I want to sort a particular range () of data but I don't want the staff using the workbook to have the passwords protecting the sheets.  So yes, ideally, I would like a macro button for them to click for both the custom sorts.  All help, very, very appreciated! Dynamically!!!

The details that I posted were what the Macro recorded when I did it that way

Do the sheets to be sorted all have the same layout (same column order, column headers always on the first row)?  Is the number or rows different between sheets?

All sheets are exactly the same layout

You can sort on multiple columns in a single sort.  For example, assuming headers are on row 1, this will sort on column A and then D:
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'always runs on the active sheet
    
    With ws.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                        Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("D2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                        Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    
        .SetRange ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion '## assumes no blanks rows or columns in data table
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub


Thank you, I'll try that.  I have to add for the sheet to be unprotected at the start and protected again at the end, but I think I know how to do that??

There may be blank cells within the range to be sorted

Would be fine as long as no completely empty rows or columns....  Basically select A1 and press Ctrl+A and see if the whole table is selected by that.
